# equal height layout with scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a layout as follows:

```
     <div class="lower-content">
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="scrollbox">
                    ........
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/616x697/AA6600" alt="middle image" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <p> .....
                </p>
                <img alt="Small Image" src="http://placehold.it/194x219/446600" />
            </div>
      </div>
```

My so far attempt is shown in the fiddle

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/gg47G/2/

**For better view**: http://jsfiddle.net/gg47G/2/show

**Question**: What I want is same height for all three column's and responsive till screen width=768px. I have figured out the layout for phone (below 768px), just the desktop and tablet version left.

**Browser**: I need a solution to work for IE8 too.

Adding margin and padding to the `col-3` is acceptable, but the height should match `col1`and `col2`
Jquery solution is acceptable but no external library. Although I would prefer css solution but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: For equal-height columns, as long as you are targeting IE9 or higher, you can use css-only `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I need IE8 too. Plus it's not working currently, even in chrome and firefox

Comment: jQuery would provide the best cross browser compatibility if you are willing to use it. What I would do it compare the heights of each column using `$({selector}).height()`. Then set the height of each element to the height of the tallest element. You can then repeat this function in `$(window).resize(function(){})`.

Comment: I did that so far I have got `col1` and `col2` to match the height. The question is about the `col3`. Since `col3` total content is smaller in height, it leaves blank space at the bottom

Comment: @Ani - so what do you expect in terms of col3?  I would have expected there to be blank space at the bottom. (and of course, if you give it a background color, you will see that the column height is correct.)

Comment: I was wondering if I could have a better solution than that, may be changing margin on resize between the `p` tag and `img` in `col3` to match the height

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/monzoor/gNta9/4/)

here is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    commonHeightToAllDiv('.common');
});
// value will be changed if resied
$(window).resize(function(){
    commonHeightToAllDiv('.common')
});
function commonHeightToAllDiv(handeler){
    // calculating all the heights of .common
    var heights = $(handeler).map(function () {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get();

    // calculating maximum value among the heights
    var max_height_of_content_boxes = function (array)             {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    };

    // implementing maximum to all .common
    $(handeler).height(max_height_of_content_boxes(heights));
}
```

CSS codes

```
.lower-content {
    border-top: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    margin: 1% auto 0;
    padding: 1% 0 0;
    width:1200px;
}

.col-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1% 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 22%;
}
.scrollbox{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    overflow: auto;
}
.col-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1% 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 53%;

 }

.col-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 22%;
}
```

Explanation:

Each div has its dynamic height. First we need to find what are those. Then get the maximum value. And implement that value on every div. Calling responsive function to make the js code responsive.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should copy the relevant code here (the jQuery) for simple reference, and explain what you've done.  Further, the fiddle link should be a *link*, not just a url....

Comment: Thanks @cale_b for your welcome note. I will keep your suggestion in my mind next time.

Comment: @MonzoorTamal The first div doesn't have a scroll.

Comment: @Ani Question: Do you want to pick the maximum height from the divs and implement that to the divs? If yes this the solution. If no then can you explain little bit more? If dynamic height isn't the issue then you can implement a fix height to each divs.